# Two sheets in the same workbook debugging error?

Tags: excel, vba

CLOSED I HAVE A WORKING SOLUTION FOR THIS.

I am attempting to use a name of a sheet inside of a workbook.
My two sheets are called "Bank"(Sheet1) & "Replicon"(Sheet2).
When I run my code that seems functional I get a run time error with ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bank") any variation of this line of code.

Ultimately I just want Column J in Sheet 1 to populate with matching Project Names from Column E in sheet 2.

What am I missing here? I will post my full code as it might be of some help.

```
    Sub ProjectName()

Dim UserID As String, Day As String, Money As String
Dim r As Integer, s As Integer
Dim lr As Long, lr2 As Long
With ActiveSheet
Dim wsBank As Worksheet, wsRep As Worksheet
Set wsBank = Worksheets("Bank")
Set wsRep = Worksheets("Replicon")

    lr = wsBank.Cells(wsBank.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = wsRep.Cells(wsRep.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To lr
  UserID = wsBank.Cells(r, 1).Value
  Day = wsBank.Cells(r, 5).Value
  Money = wsBank.Cells(r, 6).Value
  For s = 2 To lr2
    If wsRep.Cells(s, 1).Value = UserID And wsRep.Cells(s, 2).Value = Day And wsRep.Cells(s, 3).Value = Money Then
      wsBank.Cells(s, 10).Value = wsRep.Cells(s, 5).Value
    End If
    Next s
  Next r
```

End with
End Sub

[Sheet1(Bank)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQgWR.png)
[Sheet2(Replicon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEYQT.png)

Comment: What do you mean with *"I get stopped"*? Does a runtime error occur? Or a compiler error?

Comment: Debug 9 a runtime error.

Comment: Error 9 means that probably the name of one of your sheets is wrong.

Comment: if is closed. Close the question

Comment: Ummm how? @AndréWalker sorry I'm new here, but don't see a way to.

Comment: @DrewMGE you should see a "close" option after "share edit" located at the bottom of the question, below the tags.

Comment: @DrewMGE you can post a answer too, and accept your answer to your own question. It will help other that have the same problem know how you solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is broken since VBA stops at the line-end, you may try:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Replicon").Cells(s, 1).Value = UserID And _
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Replicon").Cells(s, 2).Value = Day And _
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Replicon").Cells(s, 3).Value = Money Then

   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bank").Cells(s, 10).Value = _
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Replicon").Cells(s, 5).Value
End If
```

With the "_" you tell VBA that your statment will continue in the next line.

Comment: I just formatted it for ease of reading. Its on one long line in VBA code.

Comment: Its giving the error on this line "For r = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bank").UsedRange.Rows.Count"

Answer (score 0):

With *"get stopped before the loop begins"* I assume you mean the first/outer loop, and that you are trying to say that VBA detected a syntax error?
If so, note that in order to achieve a line break within a line of code in VB, you need to break it with an '_' character, as shown here. (I also tidied your code up a bit)

```vb
Sub TestWithLoops()
Dim UserID As String, Day As String, Money As String
Dim r As Integer, s As Integer

Dim wsBank as Worksheet, wsRep as Worksheet
Set wsBank = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bank")
Set wsRep = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Replicon")

For r = 2 To wsBank.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  UserID = wsBank.Cells(r, 1).Value
  Day = wsBank.Cells(r, 5).Value
  Money = wsBank.Cells(r, 6).Value
  For s = 2 To wsRep.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If wsRep.Cells(s, 1).Value = UserID And _
        wsRep.Cells(s, 2).Value = Day And _
        wsRep.Cells(s, 3).Value = Money Then
      wsBank.Cells(s, 10).Value = _
      wsRep.Cells(s, 5).Value
    End if
    Next s
  Next r
End Sub
```

Another potential stumbling block can be the *Integer* declaration for long data sets, as VBA Integers are 16 bit and only count to 32,767 - Consider using *Long* instead for those cases. And I would also recommend being cautious when using **UsedRange** - I have had that return both too much and too little before.

But for the use case of cross-referencing project names, personally I would go with a LOOKUP function - Might be a bit complicated if you are comparing 3 values, but you could e.g. combine those 3 columns into 1 that stays hidden and compare to that:

Sheet 2: `= A2 & B2 & C2`

Sheet 1: `= VLOOKUP ( A2 & E2 & F2 ; <Column matrix in Sheet 1> ; <Column offset to project name>; FALSE )`

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

```vb
Sub TestWithLoops()
    Dim UserID As String, Day As String, Money As String
    Dim rngB As Range, rngR As Range, rwB As Range, rwR As Range
    
    'make your code easier to read by using range variables
    '  Use ActiveWorkbook if data is not in the same workbook as this code
    Set rngB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bank").UsedRange.EntireRow
    Set rngB = rngB.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngB.Rows.Count - 1) 'offset and shrink to remove headers
    Set rngR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Replicon").UsedRange.EntireRow
    Set rngR = rngR.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngR.Rows.Count - 1)
    
    'loop over Bank rows
    For Each rwB In rngB.Rows
        UserID = rwB.Cells(1).Value
        Day = rwB.Cells(5).Value
        Money = rwB.Cells(6).Value
        For Each rwR In rngR.Rows
            'nested if's will perform faster as they only test
            '  what needs to be tested - ie. they will fail early
            If rwR.Cells(1).Value = UserID Then
                If rwR.Cells(2).Value = Day Then
                    If rwR.Cells(3).Value = Money Then
                        rwB.Cells(5).Value = rwR.Cells(5).Value
                        Exit For 'done here so stop looping...
                    End If
                End If
            End If
       Next rwR
    Next rwB
End Sub
```

Comment: As I stated in my orginal question for whatever reason my VBA gives me a debug 9 at "Set rngB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bank").UsedRange.EntireRow"

Comment: Then there's no worksheet with exact name "Bank" ?

Comment: Quite literally is a sheet inside the work book that is named "Bank" the other "Replicon". My refined code in OP will run but will populate nothing in the table.

Comment: Is the code in the workbook you're working on, or in a different workbook?  Maybe you need `ActiveWorkbook` and not `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: Check my updated code if you don't mind. I now get it to run through however am not populating anything. My originally approach was what I had found from someone's previous question. I don't know if I can share the test file I am using or not.

Comment: If nothing is getting populated then you're not making any match - suggest you split up your If test into separate tests and use breakpoints to figure out if any of your cells match.  That's much more difficult if you have all 3 tests on one line.

Comment: I went ahead and did so. Not to mention am continuing to test this and improve it. However, I am starting to think that the .Value function isn't liking my data (strings). It gets to the checks and then skips due to a non-match. Both userIDs are "Joe Bob" and were copy and pasted. I will reupdate your code with what fixed my runtime error.

Comment: I added a comment about ActiveWorkbook.  Should be no issues using Value with string cell contents - possibly you have leading/trailing spaces or other characters which are preventing a match.

Comment: Finally found the issue. I need to drink more coffee and count better. Day is technically 6 and Money 7 column respectively. SMH I'm dumb. You have been extremely helpful and I have learned much in this hour! Thank you to the moon and back Tim.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @TimWilliams

```
  Sub ProjectNames()
        Dim UserID As String, Day As String, Money As String
        Dim rngB As Range, rngR As Range, rwB As Range, rwR As Range
        
    'make your code easier to read by using rnage variables
    Set rngB = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Bank").UsedRange.EntireRow
    Set rngB = rngB.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngB.Rows.Count - 1) 'offset and shrink to remove headers
    Set rngR = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Replicon").UsedRange.EntireRow
    Set rngR = rngR.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngR.Rows.Count - 1)
    
    'loop over Bank rows
    For Each rwB In rngB.Rows
        UserID = rwB.Cells(1).Value
        Day = rwB.Cells(6).Value
        Money = rwB.Cells(7).Value
        For Each rwR In rngR.Rows
            'nested if's will perform faster as they only test
            '  what needs to be tested - ie. they will fail early
            If rwR.Cells(1).Value = UserID Then
                If rwR.Cells(2).Value = Day Then
                    If rwR.Cells(3).Value = Money Then
                        rwB.Cells(10).Value = rwR.Cells(5).Value
                        Exit For 'done here so stop looping...
                    End If
                End If
            End If
       Next rwR
    Next rwB
End Sub
```